# ¿Como alinear label e inputs en columnas usando grid collumn?

Tags: php, laravel-8, mediaqueries

Tengo un formulario sencillo de registro de clientes, quiero lograr que al usar media pantalla en la pc el formulario se ajuste para evitar uso de scroll esto claro con medias query, adjunto imagen de formulario en pantalla completa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Formulario en media pantalla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar queda muy largo el formulario, quiero en el caso de **RFC**, **numero** y **código postal** colocar los inputs y etiquetas en la misma fila, al igual que **estado** y **municipio**

agregue grid columns pero no logro alinear los label, quedan asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:

```html
<form action="{{ route('admin.clientes.store') }}" method="post" id="formulario" rol="formulario">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="modal fade text-left modalCreate" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center;">{{ __('Registrar cliente') }}</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="alert" style="display: none;">

            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-row createForm">
            <!--Grupo RFC-->
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 formulario__grupo" id="grupo__rfc">
              <label class="formulario__label">{{ __('RFC') }}:</label>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input" type="text" id="rfc" name="rfc" value="{{ old('rfc') }}" maxlength="14" required />
              <p class="formulario__input-error">El rfc debe contener entre 13 y 14 caracteres, no puede incluir simbolos ni acentos</p>
              <div id="respuestaRFC"></div>
            </div>
            <!--Termina grupo RFC-->

            <!--Grupo razon social-->
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 formulario__grupo" id="grupo__razonSocial">
              <label class="formulario__label">{{ __('Razon Social') }}:</label>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input razonSocial" type="text" id="razonSocial" name="razonSocial" value="{{ old('razonSocial') }}" required />
              <p class="formulario__input-error">El campo no puede estar vacio/El campo no puede incluir simbolos</p>
            </div>
            <!--Termina grupo razon social-->
          </div>

          <div class="form-row createForm my-3">
            <!--Grupo calle-->
            <div class="form-group col-md-7 formulario__grupo" id="grupo__calle">
              <label class="formulario__label">{{ __('Calle') }}:</label>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input" type="text" id="calle" name="calle" value="{{ old('calle') }}" />
              <p class="formulario__input-error">El campo no puede incluir simbolos</p>
            </div>
            <!--Termina grupo calle-->
            <!--Grupo numero-->
            <div class="form-group col-md-2 formulario__grupo grid" id="grupo__numero">
              <label class="formulario__label">{{ __('Número') }}:</label>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input" type="text" id="numero" name="numero" value="{{ old('numero') }}" maxlength="6" />
            </div>
            <!--Termina grupo numero-->
            <!--  -->
            <div class="form-group col-md-3 formulario__grupo grid" id="grupo__codigoPostal">
              <label class="formulario__label">{{ __('Codigo postal') }}:</label>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input" type="text" id="codigoPostal" name="codigoPostal" value="{{ old('codigoPostal') }}" maxlength="6" />
            </div>
            <!--  -->
          </div>

          <!--Grupo email-->
          <div class="form-row createForm">

            <!--Grupo colonia-->
            <div class="form-group col-md-7 formulario__grupo">
              <label class="formulario__label">{{ __('Colonia') }}:</label>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input" type="text" id="colonia" name="colonia" value="{{ old('colonia') }}" />
            </div>
            <!--Termina grupo colonia-->
            <div class="form-group col-md-5 formulario__grupo" id="grupo__email">
              <label class="formulario__label">{{ __('E-mail de Facturación') }}:</label>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input" type="email" id="email" name="email" />
              <p class="formulario__input-error"></p>
              <div id="errorEmailCreate"></div>
              <div id="respuestaEmail"></div>
            </div>
            <!--Termina grupo email-->

          </div>

          <div class="form-row createForm">

            <!--Grupo telefono-->
            <div class="form-group col-md-3 formulario__grupo" id="grupo__telefono">
              <strong>{{ __('Teléfono') }}:</strong>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input" type="text" id="telefono" name="telefono" value="{{ old('telefono') }}" maxlength="10" />
              <p class="formulario__input-error">El campo no puede incluir simbolos, acentos, letras</p>
              <div id="respuestaTelefono"></div>
            </div>
            <!--Termina grupo telefono-->

            <div class="form-group col-md-3 formulario__grupo" id="grupo__estado">
              <strong>{{ __('Estado') }}:</strong>
              <select class="form-control formulario__input" name="searchEstado" id="searchEstado"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3 formulario__grupo" id="grupo__municipio">
              <strong>{{ __('Municipio') }}:</strong>
              <select class="form-control" name="municipioCreate" id="municipioCreate"></select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer formulario__grupo formulario__grupo-btn-enviar">

            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="col">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" id="RegresarCliente" onclick="Back()">
                  <span style="color:white"></span> {{ __('Regresar') }}
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="col">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary formulario__btn" id="guardarCliente">{{ __('Guardar') }}
            </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo pude solucionar, no tuve que usar grid en realidad era mas sencillo

Me apoye de este articulo **https://blogandweb.com/hacer-dos-columnas-con-css/**

Y al final quedo de esta forma mi media query:

```css
  .createForm {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .createForm>div {
    width: 50%;
  }
```

```html
<form action="{{ route('admin.clientes.store') }}" method="post" id="formulario" rol="formulario">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="modal fade text-left modalCreate" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center;">{{ __('Registrar cliente') }}</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="alert" style="display: none;">

            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-row createForm">
            <!--Grupo RFC-->
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 formulario__grupo" id="grupo__rfc">
              <label class="formulario__label">{{ __('RFC') }}:</label>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input" type="text" id="rfc" name="rfc" value="{{ old('rfc') }}" maxlength="14" required />
              <p class="formulario__input-error">El rfc debe contener entre 13 y 14 caracteres, no puede incluir simbolos ni acentos</p>
              <div id="respuestaRFC"></div>
            </div>
            <!--Termina grupo RFC-->

            <!--Grupo razon social-->
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 formulario__grupo" id="grupo__razonSocial">
              <label class="formulario__label">{{ __('Razon Social') }}:</label>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input razonSocial" type="text" id="razonSocial" name="razonSocial" value="{{ old('razonSocial') }}" required />
              <p class="formulario__input-error">El campo no puede estar vacio/El campo no puede incluir simbolos</p>
            </div>
            <!--Termina grupo razon social-->
          </div>

          <div class="form-row createForm my-3">
            <!--Grupo calle-->
            <div class="form-group col-md-7 formulario__grupo" id="grupo__calle">
              <label class="formulario__label">{{ __('Calle') }}:</label>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input" type="text" id="calle" name="calle" value="{{ old('calle') }}" />
              <p class="formulario__input-error">El campo no puede incluir simbolos</p>
            </div>
            <!--Termina grupo calle-->
            <!--Grupo numero-->
            <div class="form-group col-md-2 formulario__grupo grid" id="grupo__numero">
              <label class="formulario__label">{{ __('Número') }}:</label>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input" type="text" id="numero" name="numero" value="{{ old('numero') }}" maxlength="6" />
            </div>
            <!--Termina grupo numero-->
            <!--  -->
            <div class="form-group col-md-3 formulario__grupo grid" id="grupo__codigoPostal">
              <label class="formulario__label">{{ __('Codigo postal') }}:</label>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input" type="text" id="codigoPostal" name="codigoPostal" value="{{ old('codigoPostal') }}" maxlength="6" />
            </div>
            <!--  -->
          </div>

          <!--Grupo email-->
          <div class="form-row createForm">

            <!--Grupo colonia-->
            <div class="form-group col-md-7 formulario__grupo">
              <label class="formulario__label">{{ __('Colonia') }}:</label>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input" type="text" id="colonia" name="colonia" value="{{ old('colonia') }}" />
            </div>
            <!--Termina grupo colonia-->
            <div class="form-group col-md-5 formulario__grupo" id="grupo__email">
              <label class="formulario__label">{{ __('E-mail de Facturación') }}:</label>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input" type="email" id="email" name="email" />
              <p class="formulario__input-error"></p>
              <div id="errorEmailCreate"></div>
              <div id="respuestaEmail"></div>
            </div>
            <!--Termina grupo email-->

          </div>

          <div class="form-row createForm">

            <!--Grupo telefono-->
            <div class="form-group col-md-3 formulario__grupo" id="grupo__telefono">
              <strong>{{ __('Teléfono') }}:</strong>
              <input class="form-control formulario__input" type="text" id="telefono" name="telefono" value="{{ old('telefono') }}" maxlength="10" />
              <p class="formulario__input-error">El campo no puede incluir simbolos, acentos, letras</p>
              <div id="respuestaTelefono"></div>
            </div>
            <!--Termina grupo telefono-->

            <div class="form-group col-md-3 formulario__grupo" id="grupo__estado">
              <strong>{{ __('Estado') }}:</strong>
              <select class="form-control formulario__input" name="searchEstado" id="searchEstado"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3 formulario__grupo" id="grupo__municipio">
              <strong>{{ __('Municipio') }}:</strong>
              <select class="form-control" name="municipioCreate" id="municipioCreate"></select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer formulario__grupo formulario__grupo-btn-enviar">

            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="col">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" id="RegresarCliente" onclick="Back()">
                  <span style="color:white"></span> {{ __('Regresar') }}
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="col">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary formulario__btn" id="guardarCliente">{{ __('Guardar') }}
            </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Hay que hacer todavía algunos ajustes pero ya se logro lo que quería.